# GWT History - onValueChange event fires twice

Tags: gwt

I have included History support in my GWT application. For some reason the onValueChange event  is firing twice. Once with the correct history token and again with a blank history token. I am running this in Netbeans in hosted mode. i have only added the history handler once in the onModuleLoad of my application.

Have been struggling with this for the last week. any help is much appreciated.

Comment: a bit of issolated code demonstrating the issue would be useful because I dont have this issue in my apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

I was adding the new history item on the onclick of an anchor and therefore i needed to add     event.getNativeEvent().preventDefault(); after the new history item was added.

see code below.

public void onClick(ClickEvent event) { 
    History.newItem(Views.home.toString()); 
    event.getNativeEvent().preventDefault(); 
}

i hope this can help other people.